# Perl references. How do we know it is one?

Tags: perl, reference

I am new to Perl and reading about references.
I can not understand how doe one know if the variable he work on is a reference.
For instance if I understand correctly, this:
`$b = $a` could be assigning `scalars` or `references`. How do we know which is it?
In `C` or `C++` we would know via the function signature (`*a` or `&a` of `**a`). But in `Perl` there is no signature of parameters.
So how do we know in code what is a reference and what is not? Or if it is a reference to scalar or array or hash or another reference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perl has a [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) that you can use for that:

> Returns a non-empty string if EXPR is a reference, the empty string otherwise. [...]

The string returned (if non-empty) will tell you the type of object the reference references.

Comment: So it is common to use this to check the type?But reference to what type?

Comment: I don't know about "common", but yes that's the function you use if you need to know if something references something else. Re: your edited comment: click the link.

Comment: @Jim, no, it's not common. You should never have to use it.

Answer (score 4):

You're asking the wrong question.

While there is a function called [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) and another called [`reftype`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar%3a%3aUtil), these are not functions you should ever need to use.

It's bad to check the type of variables, because there's no way to effectively know without actually using it as intended due to overloading and magic.

For example, say you designed a function that accepts a reference or a string. That would be a bad design because an object that overloads stringification is both.

A good interface would use context to differentiate the arguments. For example, it could differentiate based on the number of arguments,

```
foo($point_obj)
   -vs-
foo(x => $x, y => $y)
```

based on the value of other arguments,

```
foo(fh => $fh)
   -vs-
foo(str => $file_contents)
```

or based on the choice of function called

```
foo_from_fh($fh)
   -vs-
foo($file_contents)
```

So the answer is: You know it's a reference because your documentation instructs the caller of your function to pass a reference. If you got passed something other than a reference and it's used as a reference, the caller will get a strict error for their error.

Answer (score 1):

The `ref` function is what you're looking for.  Documentation is available at http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html

> `ref EXPR`
>
> Returns a non-empty string if EXPR is a reference, the empty string otherwise. If EXPR is
> not specified, $_ will be used. The value returned depends on the type of thing the
> reference is a reference to...